# Forcing multicolumn to ignore extra spacing between two columns

Tags: tables, columns, multicolumn

I need to separate some groups of columns in a table by adding extra space between them. However, if there are headings specified inside of a multicolumn of width one, the heading right before the added space is centered around the area including the space. Here is a MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}  

    \begin{tabular}{lcc@{\hskip 0.5in}cc}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} \\
    Line 1 & One &Two& Three & Four\\
    Line 2 & Five & Six & Seven & Eight
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{lcc@{\hskip 0.5in}cc}
    & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
    Line 1 & One &Two& Three & Four\\
    Line 2 & Five & Six & Seven & Eight
    \end{tabular}

    \end{document}
```

The first tabular misplaces (2) and (3) compared to the second one:
[image]

Is there a way to force the first to behave the same as the second while keeping the multicolumn definitions in the first row?

Note: I know it is not ideal to have multicolumns of length 1, but these are generated automatically using Stata's esttab package and I am not aware of a solution how to go around this. For the same reason I cannot add an extra column between (2) and (3).

Comment: If you do not use any `\multicolumn` elsewhere, then do `\renewcommand{\multicolumn}{#3}`.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I do use it elsewhere in the document. Besides, even in the MWE this executes the following error: `Illegal parameter number in definition of \multicolumn. \renewcommand{\multicolumn}{#3}`

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot the parameters, sorry, but if you use it somewhere else it is no option.

Answer (score 1):

You had omitted the space specification in the `\multicolumn`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}  

\begin{tabular}{lcc@{\hskip 0.5in}cc}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{\hskip 0.5in}}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} \\
Line 1 & One &Two& Three & Four\\
Line 2 & Five & Six & Seven & Eight
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lcc@{\hskip 0.5in}cc}
& (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
Line 1 & One &Two& Three & Four\\
Line 2 & Five & Six & Seven & Eight
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this does not help me. The `\multicolumn` space specification is not created by me but automatically from Stata and as far as I know I cannot control it. I can only control what is inside of the third argument.

Comment: OK, so I've experimented a bit with this solution and I can make it work using this way. There is, however, one little glitch - the answer does fix the position of (2), however, (3) is still a bit misplaced. Is there a way to similalry redefine the `\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}` part?

Comment: @RadekJanhuba oh  you want `@{}c` in that case.